# Magento 2: How to add row in an product attribute view

Tags: product-attribute

I've been searching on how to do this. I want to display my attributes like this image: https://s29.postimg.org/8yd26i0w7/Capture.png

Each product attributes have it's own row, which makes reading it very easy :)

Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I kind of figured it out. In the attribute > products > choose an attribute. Choose the Catalog Input Type for Store Owner "text area" and you will be able to display your attributes in a

something

to make it display like that picture I posted.